# how to map() in JSX ? ERROR: Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ejs

Console.log shows objects that I think can be displayed with map (). However, there is an error "Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."
[image: error pic]

Where is the problem and how can I map() objects? Thanks!
I export contacts.js in App.jsx:

```
export const contacts = [
  {
    name: "Beyonce",
    imgURL:
      "https://blackhistorywall.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/picture-device-independent-bitmap-119.jpg",
    phone: "+123 456 789",
    email: "b@beyonce.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Jack Bauer",
    imgURL:
      "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/625247595825246208/X3XLea04_400x400.jpg",
    phone: "+987 654 321",
    email: "jack@nowhere.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Chuck Norris",
    imgURL:
      "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e3/94/47/e39447de921955826b1e498ccf9a39af.png",
    phone: "+918 372 574",
    email: "gmail@chucknorris.com"
  }
];
```

App.jsx look like:

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "./Card";
import { contacts } from "../contacts";

function App() {
  contacts.map((item) => {
    return <Card name={item.name} img={item.imgURL} phone={item.phone} email={item.email} />
  }
  )
}

export default App;
```

And Card component:

```
import React from "react";

export const Card = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="heading">My Contacts</h1>
            <div className="card">
                <div className="top">
                    <h2 className="name">{props.name}</h2>
                    <img className="circle-img"
                        src={props.img}
                        alt="avatar_img"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="bottom">
                    <p className="info">{props.phone}</p>
                    <p className="info">{props.email}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The error message has told you everything. Nothing is returned in render method. In your App.jsx, there is no `return` statement at the top level of `App()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `return` statement in the `App` component:

```js
function App() {
  return contacts.map((item) => {
    return <Card name={item.name} img={item.imgURL} phone={item.phone} email={item.email} />
  }
  )
}
```

Notice the `return` before `contacts.map`

Comment: yeah! you're right! I spend one hour on this  

Comment: I thought return is not necessary and it is by default inside App() {
<--here by default -->
}

Comment: `App` is just like any other regular JS function, so yeah you need a `return` statement, glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you have not `return` any component in your `App()`. try this:

```
function App() {
  return contacts.map((item) => {
    return <Card name={item.name} img={item.imgURL} phone={item.phone} email={item.email} />
  }
  )
}
```

Comment: @SweetCaramel happy to help. I would be grateful if my answer solves your problem, set it as an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Code**

App.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "./Card";
import { contacts } from "../contacts";

function App() {

const arrayMap = contacts.map((item) => {
    return <Card 
            name={item.name} 
            img={item.imgURL} 
            phone={item.phone} 
            email={item.email} 
           />
  })
return (
      //Load arrayMap here..
    { arrayMap }
);

}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put all your logic on the same js file for simplicity here?

```
import React from "react";
import { contacts } from "../contacts";

function App() {
    const card = contacts.map((contact, index) => (
        <div className="card" key={index}>
            <div className="top">
                <h2 className="name">{contact.name}</h2>
                <img className="circle-img"
                    src={contact.img}
                    alt="avatar_img"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="bottom">
                <p className="info">{contact.phone}</p>
                <p className="info">{contact.email}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ));
    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="heading">My Contacts</h1>
            {card}
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```